# Radiation force on a charged emitting particle

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Maxwell equations allows us to calculate the electromagnetic fields based on the motion of charged particles. On the other hand, to see how particles are affected by those fields, you add the Lorentz force, which  is an approximation at low speeds, so it is [modified relativistically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Translation_to_vector_notation).
The modification is $d\vec{p}/dt=q(\vec E + \vec v$ x$ \vec B) $ with $\vec{p}=\gamma m_0 \vec{v}$, which results in extra terms that slows the particle.

The Lorentz force generalization introduce terms opposing the speed and the acceleration that modify the classical path.

For instance, a charged particle moving in a circle in a magnetic field will end up spiraling inwards and losing energy. Because the magnetic force does not do work, is this change in energy dues to the emitted radiation?

On the other hand, you can calculate the radiation force using a different argument and you reach a different conclusion, that the force is a [function of jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force). Is this a second mechanism that emits energy and must be introduced ad hoc in the Lorentz force, in addition to the relativistic modification?

Comment: I think you are confused about the Lorentz force. What do you think the equation is for the non-relativistic Lorentz force? And what do you think the relativistic modification  is?

Comment: @G.Smith I linked it on the main text

Comment: $d\mathbf{p}/dt=q(\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B})$ is just the spatial part of $dp^\alpha/d\tau=qF^{\alpha\beta}U_\beta$. The latter is not a relativistic correction to the first. It is the first written in “manifestly covariant” form.

Comment: @G.Smith I clarified in the text why I say that

Comment: Now you’re talking about the relativistic redefinition of Newtonian momentum. That has nothing to do with the Lorentz force, which was relativistic to begin with.

Comment: @G.Smith thanks, let me think about it

Comment: @G.Smith you are right, the correction does not change the fact that a pure magnetic force cant do work. Regarding the radiation force mentioned in the second place, is this an addition to the Lorentz force which otherwise would be incomplete due to the fact that it does not deal with radiation?

Comment: That’s a subtle question. The simple answer is Yes, the Abraham-Lorentz radiation reaction force is not part of the Lorentz force. The more complicated answer, I think, is that a careful analysis of the Lorentz *self*-force exerted on an accelerating point charge *by its own field* can explain the radiation reaction force.

Comment: @G.Smith thanks for pointing me in the right direction